# How to open and save file thru notepad by C# console program

Tags: c#, save, notepad

I already know that I can open and close an exist text file by notepad in c#
Like this:

```
using System.Diagnostics;

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {        
        // open by notepad
        Process.Start("notepad.exe", @"myfile.txt");

        // automatically save this file by notepad

        // kill notepad process
        Process[] proc = Process.GetProcessesByName("notepad");
        proc[0].Kill();   
    }
}
```

But I need to automatically save this file by notepad before I close this file. I tried to send keystrokes ctrl+s but in vain.
Is there .net code for this? Thanks.

Comment: What do you want to be happening between opening and save? User input?

Comment: To my knowledge, you can't. `Notepad.exe` would need to expose an API for that, which to my knowledge, it doesn't. Further, your code does not kill the instance of notepad which it opened - it kills the first instance of notepad it finds.

Comment: @RistoM  actually nothing, just need the notepad to save the text file. Before saving it, the encoding of the file is UCS-2 Little Endian. After saving it by notepad, it turned to UCS-2 LE BOM. I need this file's encoding become UCS-2 LE BOM.

Comment: @DavidStockinger  I see... Thanks for reminding of the kill process. ^^

Comment: @KateChang Ok, that's what I thought. I think this encoding fix is doable in C# also, with classes like System.Text.Encoding..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like this i guess

[SendKeys.SendWait Method (String)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.sendkeys.sendwait(v=vs.110).aspx)

> Sends the given keys to the active application, and then waits for the
>   messages to be processed.

**Remarks**

> Use SendWait to send keystrokes or combinations of keystrokes to the
>   active application and wait for the keystroke messages to be
>   processed. You can use this method to send keystrokes to an
>   application and wait for any processes that are started by the
>   keystrokes to be completed. This can be important if the other
>   application must finish before your application can continue.

**Imports**

```
[DllImport("User32.dll")]   
public static extern Int32 SetForegroundWindow(int hWnd);
```

**Code**

```
var process = Process.Start("notepad.exe", @"myfile.txt"));
process.WaitForInputIdle();
var handle = process.MainWindowHandle;
SetForegroundWindow(handle);

// if the window is still in the foreground
SendKeys.SendWait("^(s)"); // Ctrl+S
```

Answer (score 0):

If your need is to modify file, better way to do that is open, modify and save text file contents with operations which are currently present in [System.IO.File](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file(v=vs.110).aspx)-class. When file is opened in code, you can i.e change it's encodings with classes found in [System.Text](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kdcak6ye(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-2)-namespace (System.Text.Encoding).

You can start `notepad.exe` process, but after that there is not very much to do.

Comment: OP didn't ask for opinions on others things they could do, so this doesn't really answer the question. Also, you don't even explain how to achieve your suggestion, I think this is a comment at best

Comment: You are right. And therefore I asked some additional info from OP in my comment. After getting some input, I'll improve this answer (or remove, if need is really to play with notepad).